# Inserting html elements into another html elements with several classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert

I am developing a web application, the application contains the following elements:

```
<div id="flip" class="container">
        <div class="f-page f-cover" id="cover">
            <div class="cover-elements">
                <div class="f-cover-story">
                    <span>Life Events</span>Photo Album
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="f-cover-flip">&lt; swipe</div>
        </div>

        <div class="f-page f-cover-back">
            <div id="codrops-ad-wrapper">
                <a href="index.jsp" >Back to bookshelf</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to element html elements like other divs between

```
<div class="f-page f-cover" id="cover">
                <div class="cover-elements">
                    <div class="f-cover-story">
                        <span>Life Events</span>Photo Album
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-cover-flip">&lt; swipe</div>
            </div>
```

and

```
<div class="f-page   f-cover-back">
                    <div id="codrops-ad-wrapper">
                        <a href="index.jsp" >Back to bookshelf</a>
                    </div>

            </div>
```

For that i searched the jquery framework and found out the .insertAfter method.

So this is what i tried so far:

```
$(result_html).insertAfter( "#cover" );
```

where result_html is my string that is loaded with the html elements i want to add

and

```
$(result_html).insertAfter( ".f-page f-cover" );
```

in the first i tried to add it with the id of the div i wanted to place it next to and the second was the class i was refering.

Although in jquery [insertafter method](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) uses the class of the div, in my case my div has 2 class names.

How can i solve this? currently nothing is being inserted next the f-page f-cover div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're selecting elements with multiple classes, you can't use a space between those classes. This would select `parent children`.

This will insert after the element(s) with both classes:

```
$(result_html).insertAfter( ".f-page.f-cover" );
```

This will insert after the element with the id:

```
$(result_html).insertAfter( "#cover" );
```

Both work fine: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/btpbeq6m/2/)

Answer (score 1):

First in your post you forgot second dot for `$(result_html).insertAfter( ".f-page f-cover" );`

Next, even if you add this dot (like this `$(result_html).insertAfter( ".f-page .f-cover" );`) you will access element with class 'f-cover' that is inside element with class 'f-page'. But this is not what you need.

This is what you need -

```
$(result_html).insertAfter( ".f-page.f-cover" );
```